# Download image files from google cloud storage bucket to IOS localstorage using meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, google-cloud-storage

I am using Meteor project to upload images to the google cloud from iOS device and download the same images to iOS device.

I don't get any issues while uploading the images, it gets stored in google storage bucket. The issue I am facing is while downloading the images, I am using below code which downloads the images on server's path.

```
bucket.file(srcFilename).download(options);
```

I want to download and store the images on iOS device.
When I tried to read the file using createReadStream, my app get stuck without any progress (Not getting any callback).

```
  bucket.file(srcFilename).createReadStream()
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log("error");
  })
  .on('response', function(response) {
    // Server connected and responded with the specified status and
    console.log("response");
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    // The file is fully downloaded.
    console.log("The file is fully downloaded.");
  })
```

I hope that I am not missing anything while downloading the images to iOS device. I looked but unable to find any other option to do the same.

Any help in this regard is really appreciated as I am stuck at this very point.

Answer (score 0):

I used below code to get the file from google cloud and download the chunks which I converted to binary format. Then I used this binary format to display image and store in my local storage from client side.

```
var chunkNew = new Buffer('');

 bucket.file(srcFilename).createReadStream().on('data', function (chunk) {
    chunkNew = Buffer.concat([chunkNew,chunk]);
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    // The file is fully downloaded.
    callback(null, chunkNew.toString('base64'));
  })
```

More information can be found in this link http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-04-nodejs-readable-streams.html which uses data chunk to show the image as array buffer.